# if the variable depends on $\theta$, like $x>\theta$, indicator s.t $I_{(\theta,\infty)}{x}$ be used, what if $x>0$, should I still use indicator?

Tags: statistical-inference

For finding the minimal sufficient statistic, if the variable depends on the unknown parameter, like $x>\theta$, we should use indicator s.t $I_{(\theta,\infty)}{x}$, but if the variable is just like $x>0$, should I still use indicator? Thanks for your help.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, when the support does not depends on the unknown parameter(s), the indicator will simply indicate the support of your distribution and won't construct the sufficient statistic. Hence, I think it will be ok to omit them.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help